# Wie heißt der untere Rand eines Pullovers oder Sweatshirts?

Tags: single-word-request

Laut Duden ist ein *Bund* die "Einfassung eines Rocks, einer Hose in der Taille durch einen festen Stoffstreifen oder ein Gurtband". Ein *Bündchen* ist ein "von einem geraden Stoffstreifen gebildeter Abschluss am Halsausschnitt oder an Ärmeln bestimmter Kleidungsstücke". Ausdrücklich nicht genannt in den Definitionen beider Begriffe ist der Abschluss von Oberkörperbekleidung in der Taille durch einen geraden Stoffstreifen.

Im Internet wird dieser Teil abwechselnd Bund und Bündchen genannt. Wie heißt er richtig?

Das [auf Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bund_(Textil)) zitierte *Bekleidungs-Lexikon* von Wilfried Schierbaum kann ich leider online nicht einsehen. Im Wikipedia-Artikel wird auch der Taillenabschluss von Pullovern als Bündchen bezeichnet, aber ich bezweifle, dass das richtig ist, da ich mir unter der Verkleinerungsform *(-chen)* immer den Abschluss einer *kleinen* Kleidungsöffnung vorstelle, während ja die untere Öffnung eines Pullovers mindestens die Größe eines Hosen*bundes* hat.

Gibt es jemanden hier, der das *Bekleidungs-Lexikon* einsehen kann oder eine andere verlässliche Quelle hat? Ich würde gerne die korrekte, textiltechnische Bezeichnung wissen.

[image]

Comment: "Ausdrücklich nicht genannt" bedeutet, dass ein Kommentar oder eine Fußnote o.dgl. darauf hinweist, dass das Element am unteren Rand von Pullovern nicht in Frage kommt. Kann es sein, dass Du einfach sagen willst, die Taille des Pullovers werde nicht genannt? Insofern als Rock u. Hose genannt werden widersprichst Du Dir auch selbst. Rock u. Hose gehören ja zur Oberbekleidung und da geht es ausdrücklich (sic!) um die Taille.

Comment: @userunknown Ich meinte natürlich *Ober**körper**bekleidung*. Ich habe das korrigiert. Danke für den Hinweis.

Comment: @userunknown "Ausdrücklich nicht genannt" bedeutet ***nicht***, dass etwas ausdrücklich genannt und dann ausgeschlossen wird. Beispiel: "... in der Aufzählung möglicher Dritter (vgl. § 7 Abs. 1 GWG) sind deutsche Auslandsvertretungen aber ausdrücklich nicht genannt." ([Quelle](https://minsk.diplo.de/by-de/service/-/2005628)) [Im Gesetzestext](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/gwg_2017/__2.html) werden nirgendwo "deutsche Auslandsvertretungen" genannt und dann ausgeschlossen.

Comment: @userunknown Weiteres Beispiel aus einem Gerichtsurtail: "Der Beklagten ist zuzugeben, dass in § 16a Abs. 2 EnEV 2014 Makler ausdrücklich nicht genannt sind." ([Quelle](https://www.presseportal.de/pm/22521/3349163)) [Im Gesetzestext](https://www.buzer.de/gesetz/7831/a187425.htm) sind erneut Makler nirgendwo genannt und dann ausgeschlossen: "§ 16a (2) Absatz 1 ist entsprechend anzuwenden auf den Vermieter, Verpächter und Leasinggeber bei Immobilienanzeigen zur Vermietung, Verpachtung oder zum Leasing eines Gebäudes, einer Wohnung oder einer sonstigen selbständigen Nutzungseinheit."

Comment: @userunknown "Ausdrücklich nicht genannt" bedeutet, dass die Nichtnennung absichtsvoll geschieht, wovon man beispielsweise bei Gesetztestexten ausgehen muss. Gesetze nennen "ausdrücklich", wann, wo und für wen sie gelten, d.h. sie führen explizit in Form einer Liste jeden einzelnen Fall auf. Alles was nicht genannt ist, ist in der Regel ausgenommen und wurde absichtsvoll nicht aufgeführt. Gesetztestexte listen eben gerade *nicht* auf, wann und wo und für wen sie *nicht* gelten.

Comment: Eben. Bei Gesetzestexten ist die Nichtnennung in einer Liste bedeutungsvoll. Das kann man von einer des Duden u.ä. Werke kaum behaupten. Die Nichtnennung von "Abschluss von Oberkörperbekleidung in der Taille" ist eine dermaßen eingeschränkte Teilmenge, dass mir "ausdrückliche Nichtnennung" als ein an den Haaren herbeigezogenes Kriterium erscheint. Man könnte auch sagen, dass "blaue Wollbündchen am linken Pulloverarm" ausdrücklich ausgeschlossen sind.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: Ich habe keinen Zugriff auf ein Fachlexikon und bin auch kein Experte.

Bund scheint mir korrekt zu sein. Ich würde die Verkleinerungsform für den unteren Abschluss ausschließen. Alternativ käme Saum in Betracht, wobei das eher auf die Verarbeitung zielt, die ein Ausfransen des Stoffs an sich verhindert.

Saum würde ich immer dann verwenden, wenn ein Kleinungstück wie hier dadurch zusammengezogen wird, z.B. damit es glatt an der Hose anliegt. Eine typische über der Beinbekleidung getragene Damenbluse etwa hat keinen Saum.

Comment: Ergänzend: *Bündchen* wird eher für den Abschluss der Ärmel verwendet, siehe [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/B%C3%BCndchen).

Answer (score 2):

Als Bündchen wird der Stoff bezeichnet, der extra an die Öffnung eines Kleidungsstück angenäht wird. Das wird eher selten an den Öffnungen für den Bauch gemacht, eher an den Öffnungen am Ärmel, oder auch in schmalen Streifen am Kragen. Diese Art Abschluss ist elastisch. Beispiel: https://www.ottobredesign.com/retail/img/browse/2024_1/6_big.jpg

Wenn der Stoff, aus dem das Kleidungsstück besteht, umgeschlagen und vernäht wird, dann wird das als Saum bezeichnet. Beispiel: https://www.ottobredesign.com/retail/img/browse/2024_1/3_big.jpg

Ein Bund wiederrum ist meist aus dem gleichen Stoff wie das Kleidungsstück, doch durch eine zweite Stoffschicht nochmals verstärkt. Das wird eher bei Hosen benutzt, ganz typisch bei Jeans.Eine Sonderform wäre hier der Gummibund, bei dem noch ein Gummi in den Stofftunnel eingezogen wird, zB bei Jogginhosen.

Ich habe leider auch keine Quelle dafür. Da ich aber gerne selbst Kleidung nähe, habe ich viele Anleitungen für Schnittmuster gelesen.